# What is it called when something is unimportant for several years, and then it becomes important?

Tags: phrase-requests

I've been writing a paper about a math concept (called "permanent") that, upon its discovery, nobody really cared about it because it has very few useful properties. It was until several years later that someone realised that it is actually pretty important/interesting.

So, as you can observe, I'm talking about something that has been "on the dark" for several years, and then suddenly it was the boom.

How do you describe such thing? Something that was apparently completely useless and then it became fairly important? For context, I'm trying to figure out a nice title for the paper.

Here's a dumb version of the title I'm trying to make up:

> The permanent: rise from nothing to something.

Comment: A 'math concept (called "permanent") that, upon its discovery, nobody really cared about it because it has very few useful properties'? I thought that was a necessary condition for a mathematical bombshell.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think its time under the shadows was much more prolonged that other concepts. Well, I dunno.

Comment: Omega, it looks better now.

Comment: It's called an unforeseen crisis.

Answer (score 3):

**[Dormant](http://i.word.com/idictionary/dormant)**

> ... **2** : marked by a suspension of activity ...
>
> The idea lay dormant.

Other possibilities are *latent* or *quiescent*.

> The latent potential went unnoticed. The idea lay quiescent for some time.

Comment: I couldn't improve on 'The idea lay dormant.'

Answer (score 3):

I don't often distinguish a phrase as having the perfect context but I think the common phrase **ahead of its time**, is perfect here.

Answer (score 2):

A phrase I've been hearing more of recently is *dark horse*, defined by [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dark%20horse) as

> 1a. a usually little known contender (as a racehorse) that makes an unexpectedly good showing

But *little known* could also mean that the *dark horse* is a brand-new thing; *dark horse* may not capture the period of being virtually unknown or overlooked. For this, consider *sleeper*, defined by [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleeper) to mean

> 4:  someone or something unpromising or unnoticed that suddenly attains prominence or value: *the low-budget film became the summer's sleeper*

This term is commonly used for cinema as [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_hit) observes in its description of *sleeper hit*:

> A **sleeper hit** is a term used in the entertainment industry for a film that plays successfully for a long period and becomes a big success, despite having relatively little promotion or lacking a successful opening. It is also used in a similar sense for music releases.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the phrase "out of the shadows into the limelight."

> [There seems to be an unexplainable fear for A&M to step out of the shadows into the limelight of major college sports.](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22into+the+limelight%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=pt&client=safari#hl=pt&q=%22out+of+the+shadows+into+the+limelight+of%22)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a phrase that is synonymous with sudden fame and popularity after years of relative obscurity, consider the following:

- **Catapulted** *into the limelight*

> *His brilliant performance in the play catapulted him to stardom*    <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catapult)</sub>

Often used when referring to actors, film directors etc. whose talents were either ignored, unappreciated or underestimated by critics and the public alike until they get "discovered" in a hugely successful film which launches them, figuratively speaking, to overnight stardom. This is an effective analogy for the math concept "permanent".

> Until recently the role of "permanent" had been gravely underestimated
>   when it was *catapulted into the limelight* ....

Continuing with the analogy we have the expressions

- **Rise from obscurity to stardom**
  <sub>[Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22obscurity%20to%20stardom%22&num=30&client=firefox-a&hs=elL&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=nz1UU7Ra7efhBOOQgZgK&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1339&bih=588)</sub>
- **Rise from obscurity to fame**
  <sub>[Google books](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=bks&q=%22obscurity%20to%20fame%22&oq=%22obscurity%20to%20fame%22&gs_l=serp.12...3886.7564.0.9668.11.11.0.0.0.0.182.1168.6j5.11.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..8.3.380.oJGIZDjJZTI)</sub>

> Permanent: The rise from obscurity to stardom
>   Permanent ignored by many in the world of mathematics until it finally rose from obscurity to fame

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Eureka effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect)?

> The eureka effect, also known as the aha! moment, refers to the common human experience of suddenly understanding a previously incomprehensible problem or concept.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and too late for the OP, but I think the most obvious answer has been missed.

> The permanent: *[an idea whose time has come.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/381646-nothing-is-more-powerful-than-an-idea-whose-time-has)*